# Linker problems with gstreamer

Tags: links

I am using `adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702` with Eclipse and NDK-r8e. Can anybody help me?

```
C:\\Dev\\Android\\android-ndk-r8e\\ndk-build.cmd" all 
GStreamer      : [GEN] => gst-build-armeabi-v7a/gstreamer_android.c
GStreamer      : [COMPILE] => gst-build-armeabi-v7a/gstreamer_android.c
GStreamer      : [LINK] => gst-build-armeabi-v7a/libgstreamer_android.so
C:/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold.exe: C:/Dev/Android/gstreamer-1.0-android-universal-1.12.0/armv7/lib/libgraphene-1.0.a(libgraphene_1_0_la-graphene-matrix.o): in function graphene_matrix_interpolate:graphene-private.h:145: error: undefined reference to 'sincosf'
C:/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold.exe: C:/Dev/Android/gstreamer-1.0-android-universal-1.12.0/armv7/lib/libgraphene-1.0.a(libgraphene_1_0_la-graphene-quaternion.o): in function graphene_quaternion_init_from_radians:graphene-private.h:145: error: undefined reference to 'sincosf'
C:/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold.exe: C:/Dev/Android/gstreamer-1.0-android-universal-1.12.0/armv7/lib/libgraphene-1.0.a(libgraphene_1_0_la-graphene-quaternion.o): in function graphene_quaternion_init_from_radians:graphene-private.h:145: error: undefined reference to 'sincosf'
C:/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold.exe: C:/Dev/Android/gstreamer-1.0-android-universal-1.12.0/armv7/lib/libgraphene-1.0.a(libgraphene_1_0_la-graphene-quaternion.o): in function graphene_quaternion_init_from_radians:graphene-private.h:145: error: undefined reference to 'sincosf'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [buildsharedlibrary_armeabi-v7a] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny...solved it one day later after posting this question.
NDK-r11c and Gstreamer 1.12.0 https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/android/1.12.0/ linker works fine :)